# Is an environment plugin needed when implementing standalone Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, babeljs

I'm planning to lay Redux over a simple old-school jQuery interface to help manage UI state and make it more easily modifiable. I'm set up like so:

```
<script src=".../babel.js"></script>
<script src=".../redux.js"></script>
```

The documentation I'm looking at mentions an env plugin to allow transpilation to ES2015. Is this needed to simply get Redux working in common, modern browsers?

Comment: Depends on what you want to target, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. My overall goal is to use Redux in common browsers without a build.

Comment: You could use an already transpiled redux from: https://unpkg.com/redux@4.0.1/, then you would not need babel or env plugin.

Comment: I mean before you didn't say what you were targeting, so there was no great way to answer. Is it needed just to get Redux working? Not at all as per the docs: https://redux.js.org/faq/general#do-i-need-to-have-a-particular-build-tool-to-use-redux, and most of ES6 is mostly supported now anyway, e.g., https://medium.freecodecamp.org/you-might-not-need-to-transpile-your-javascript-4d5e0a438ca... I've used Redux + jQuery w/o a build for some PoCs and it was fine, but the production version used a build tool, so I can't speak to how much coverage we gained by building.